# It Terminal, when I type `ls Desktop`, I'm seeing temporary Word files randomly

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash, ms-office

I've never noticed this before, but randomly now in Terminal when I type `ls Desktop` I see temporary files from Microsoft Word which are prefixed with `~$` and end with: `.docx`

I don't understand where these files have come from, I tried to search online and found someone said to try to restart/shutdown your mac and open up again and they should be gone but I still see them when I type the ls command, any idea why these are randomly showing up and how I can get rid of them?

Comment: @user3439894 but in my 4 years of having this mac this has never come up till now, and I've open/closed many docs and word itself as well as switched my mac on and off but the same word hidden files in some directories appear

Comment: I let out a bit in my first comment... They will arrear and disappear on the **Desktop** as **Word** _documents_ are opened and closed by **MS Word** on the **Desktop**.

Comment: I've seen this in ~/Downloads/ too. They're just temporary files from Word. I've never tracked down exactly what causes them to be created, but they are not uncommon.

Comment: @TJLuoma I see it in ~/Downloads/ as well, it's strange because In such a long time of using my Mac this has never been there until now randomly, is there a way to somehow get rid of these files?

Comment: @user3439894 but I currently have no word files on my Desktop? if I understand you correctly

Comment: I don't use Word files all that often so I'm not sure. There may be a setting in Word. I'd look for automatic backups or something like that.